# issue with DecimalFormat in java

Tags: java

I am facing issue in below code -

```
int precision = 3;

String value1 = "2.0425";

String value2 = "2.1425";

DecimalFormat dfForm = new DecimalFormat();

dfForm.setMinimumFractionDigits(precision);

dfForm.setMaximumFractionDigits(precision);

System.out.println(dfForm.format(value1));

System.out.println(dfForm.format(value2));
```

Output -

2.042

2.143

1st output is expected to be 2.043. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: The code you've given doesn't actually give that output - it throws an exception because you're trying to format a string. Always provide a [mcve] that actually does what you claim.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for `DecimalFormat`:

> `DecimalFormat` provides rounding modes defined in `RoundingMode` for formatting. By default, it uses `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`.

It sounds like you just need:

```
dfForm.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

That's after you've fixed your code to call `format` on actual numbers, mind you:

```
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("2.0425");        
BigDecimal value2 = new BigDecimal("2.1425");
```

If you just use `double` values, you'll still see 2.042, as the nearest double to 2.0425 is 2.042499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875.